# how to increase the box width on the text size in Dynamic FilteredSelectMultiple

Tags: django, django-admin

How to increase the box width dynamically based on the text size of FilteredSelectMultiple  in django admin.

Rightnow  in my admin page i can't view complete text in the box.

[image]

Any help really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a css issue.  You'll need to edit the corresponding css for it.

Use

```
./manage.py collectstatic
```

to collect the static files for this project's admin section(so you won't be editing the django's master copy of the files).  It will place the static files in the directory that you have specified in settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/app/static/'
```

you might also need to set the static URL too.  Something like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Hint:  If you're having problems finding the exact css, (if you're in chrome for example) right click on the element, select "Inspect element" and it will highlight the element and  show the corresponding css.  It will tell you the file name and line number.  There is similar functionality for all major browsers (sometimes a plugin is necessary though)